Can't confirm the descent direction at a point

Consider the problem  \begin{equation}
 \underset{\mathbb{R}^2}{\text{min}} f (x) = \frac12x_1^4 + 2x_2^4 + x_1^2 - x_1 x_2 + x_2^2 . \end{equation} Suppose that the function $f$ is minimized starting from  $x_0=(1,1)^T$. Verify that
$p_0=(3,-2)^T$ is a  direction  of descent  at $x_0$. Compute then the
Newton and steepest-descent directions  at the point $x_0$.

Let us compute the divergence:
\begin{equation}
    \nabla f= \begin{pmatrix}
        2x_1^3+2x_1-x_2\\
        10x_2-x_1 
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
and the Hessian:
\begin{equation}
    \nabla^2 f= \begin{pmatrix}
        6x_1^2+2 & -1\\
        -1 & 10 
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Then we insert for the point $x_0=(1,1)$ in the Hessian an obtain the eigenvalues of
\begin{equation}
    \nabla^2 f= \begin{pmatrix}
        8 & -1\\
        -1 & 10 
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
are $\lambda_{1,2}=9\pm\sqrt{2}$ which is positive definite. Hence $x_0$ is a local minimizer.
We then verify the descent direction of $p_0=(3,-2)$ at $x_0$. We insert for $p_0$ in $\nabla f$ and obtain:
\begin{equation}
    d=-\nabla f= \begin{pmatrix}
        -62\\
        23 
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Let $\phi(t)=f(x_0+td)$. $\phi(t)$ should be smaller than $f(x_0)$ for small positive values of t, since $d=-\nabla f(x_0)$ is a descent direction.  Let $t=0.005$ and obtain:
\begin{equation}
     \phi (0.005)=2.05
 \end{equation}
Then calculate $f(x_0)=\frac72$
However, $f(x_0)>\phi(t)$, so something went wrong here.
Is there an obvious miscalculation here or is this the wrong approach?
Thanks

The divergence calculation is wrong. In the second term, the $x_2^4$ term.
